# How to multiply a userDefault by a number?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

how would I be able to multiply a user default by a number

my app crashes when I try to multiply my user default by a number in my `FeesVC`

It works perfectly fine passing the subtotal to the subtotalLbl (when by itself) but crashes the app if I try to multiply by any number with the `UserDefault` when trying to calculate for the salesTaxLbl and overallTotalLbl

```
class FooterCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalInfoBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func additionalFeesOnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(cartTotal.text, forKey: "PASS_DATA")
    }
}
```

---

```
class FeesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var subtotalLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var salesTaxLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var overallTotalLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // passes data into FeesVC Fine
        let subtotal = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "PASS_DATA") 

        // app crashed when trying to multiply the user default by a number
        let tax = Float(subtotal)! * Float(0.0825) 
        let total = Float(subtotal)! + Float(tax) 

        subtotalLbl.text = "\(subtotal!)"
        salesTaxLbl.text = "\(Tax)"
        overallTotalLbl.text = "\(total)"

    }

    @IBAction func returnButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Close Taxes and Fees")
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are trying to cast `Float(subtotal)` where `subtotal` is an `NSNumber`.. it needs to be converted to a raw primitive float by doing `(subtotal as! NSNumber).floatValue`.. otherwise store `subtotal` as a float and retrieve it as a float instead.

Comment: Do **not** misuse `UserDefaults` to share data between cell and controller. That's very bad practice. Use callback closure or protocol/delegate. Apart from that as you clearly write a **string** to `UserDefaults` why don't you get it back with `string(forKey:)`?

Comment: @Brandon `subtotal` is `String` (actually `Any?` when being received from `UserDefaults`)

Comment: If I read it correctly, you are force unwrapping `subtotal` in `Float(subtotal)!` - if `subtotal` does not exist, you get a crash. What does the crash log say?

Comment: @vadian I have tried using a delegate to share data between the footer cell and controller but it hasn't worked successful for me yet, I believe it might be an issue because its in the footer cell. so I changed my approach to using userdefault

Comment: @Koen yes that's exactly what's going on. and the error im getting is Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Then you need to unwrap it first: `if let subtotal = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "PASS_DATA") { let tax = Float(subtotal) * Float(0.0825)}`

Comment: It would have helped tremendously if you would have added the error in your question from the beginning. Please see [ask].

Comment: @Koen im getting an error on ```let tax = Float(subtotal) * Float(0.0825)``` saying  Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger' because only concrete types can conform to protocols. Also ill make sure to to write a moe clear question next tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with values in `UserDefaults` like this, it can often be helpful to wrap them up with a custom `get` & `set` in a variable so that you may access them like normal variables.

```
var subTotal: Float {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "PASS_DATA")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "PASS_DATA")
    }
}
```

This would give you a variable that performs like a normal `Float`, so you can operate on it without having to concern yourself about the implementation details.

Now, you can do this and everything **Just Works (tm**).

```
let tax = subtotal * Float(0.0825)
```

**Updated to show this in action.**

When a breakpoint is hit, I run the `po UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "PASS_DATA")` command in the right side of the bottom console. This allows you to query values.

When no value has been set for `PASS_DATA`, then you will get the default value of `0.0` as seen here:

[image]

However, if a value has been set, then you will see it as seen here where I set `5.0` before I print it out.

[image]

Comment: I just ran the code its not passing the data to the SubtotalLbl it works its just showing "0.0" in the label

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the get and then run `'po UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "PASS_DATA")` & check if this is the expected value.

Comment: I just ran it, I am getting  ```po UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "PASS_DATA")``` what does that mean?

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with your solution. It really helped me a lot, I just had to take some time to tinker with it lol. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should store and load your value as a float/double instead, for instance

```
@IBAction func additionalFeesOnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if let value = Float(cartTotal.text) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "PASS_DATA")
    }
    //or if you want to store a default value  
    //UserDefaults.standard.set(Float(cartTotal.text) ?? 0, forKey: "PASS_DATA")
}
```

and

```
let subtotal = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "PASS_DATA")
```

Comment: I have to add an ! to if  ```let value = Float(cartTotal.text!) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "PASS_DATA")
    }```  but the results end up being "0.0" in the Subtotal Label in the in the FeesVC

Comment: What does carttotal.text contain then? I have read through the different comments but I am not sure what the issue is right now.